# How to navigate to a directory which is specified by contents of one file?

Tags: bash

I used below 2 commands to change directory. And it seems it failed because the directory name includes space.

```
$ cat temp.temp
/cygdrive/C/training_course/Our\ Document

$ cd `cat temp.temp`
-bash: cd: /cygdrive/C/training_course/Our\: No such file or directory
```

However, below one works correctly. 
So what's wrong with above method? Is there any good way to change directory to one location specified in the contents of some file?

```
$ cd /cygdrive/C/training_course/Our\ Document
```

Comment: You can't `cd` into a `cat` command with Cygwin.  You _could_ try to create a symlink.

Comment: `cd "$(cat temp.temp)"` might work.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : it may not be so.

Comment: $ cd "`cat temp.temp`"
-bash: cd: /cygdrive/C/training_course/Our\ Document\: No such file or directory

cd "$(cat temp.temp)"
-bash: cd: /cygdrive/C/training_course/Our\ Document: No such file or directory

$ cd "/cygdrive/C/training_course/Our\ Document"
-bash: cd: /cygdrive/C/training_course/Our\ Document: No such file or directory


 @JonathanLeffler . I think the reason why above 3 methods fail is because that the space in between "Our Document" has already been escaped by \, so a double quote will NOT work here.

Comment: I'm not surprised that `cd "$(cat temp.temp)"` didn't work; the backslash in the file wreaks havoc.  And it's why it was a comment suggestion, not an answer.  If the name in the file was the name on disk — no backslash — then it would work.  I think the `read line` suggestion in the answer is about your only option.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Yes, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
read line <temp.temp && cd "$line"
```

may work.

This comes in handy when you're dealing with multiple directories in a file. If that is the case do something like :

```
while read line
do
cd "$line"
//something here
cd ..
done <temp.temp
```

Comment: And i found that the original backslash used to escape space in between "Our Document" is gone as well, so this is also expected behavior for built-in command "read"?   

$ read line <temp.temp && echo $line
/cygdrive/C/training_course/Our Document

Comment: Yes; `read` (as distinct from `read -r`) works like that (treating backslash as special).  See the POSIX specification of [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html), and the Bash manual on [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read).

Comment: @Zii : `so this also expected behaviour`? yes. However, if you use the `-r` parameter with read ie `read -r` you will get the same error you got before because `-r` parameter prevents backslash escapes from being interpreted.